# How to get the HTML code for a web page after it is fully loaded in PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, web-scraping, headless

I am trying to get the HTML code for any web page, only and only after it is fully loaded.

I tried CURL, and file_get_contents, and I understand by now that they do not wait for JavaScript to finish.

I know by now that the solution is to use a headless browser. I tried PhantomJS, but it is a little bit inefficient since the only method found to make it wait, is to set a constant timeout period.

Also, I found out that in general, it is almost impossible to get when the page actually fully load, and the best approach was to keep checking for the network data until they completely stop.

I believe to keep checking for the existence of a content in the page, would work just fine for my use, but as fast as I know, the only method to implement that is to use puppeteer package which only works well with NodeJS not PHP.

So, do you guys know about any efficient method to get the HTML code after the page is fully loaded in PHP, without going through the complex process of integrating other programming languages, or other platforms?

Comment: Unfortunately, there just isn't an easy answer to this: there is no single definition of "completely loaded", and there is no way of emulating the full functionality of a modern browser without actually running one.

Comment: I understand. Since all the threads I found was before years ago, I thought something have changed over the time. Still, I am optimistic and I feel like someone would just reveal the hidden genius method to answer my question *.*

Comment: Sorry, there's no magic wand for this one. If anything, browsers keep getting more complicated, so it keeps getting harder. The only easy way out is to challenge the premise: do you **really** need the HTML of the page, or is there somewhere else you can get the data you need? Do you really need a **universal** solution, or can you hack something together manually for the particular site you're trying to scrape?

Comment: Unfortunately, I need a universal solution, since I am trying to get data of a similar form, from multiple websites, that do not provide an API. My approach was to get the HTML contents for all of them, then scrap the data using preg_match_all method. My approach worked fine for websites in the USA using CURL. But, it feels impossible to use CURL to scrap data for UK websites, since almost all of them use Ajax to reveal the data from their databases.

Comment: Plenty of US sites, and sites across the world, use Ajax. I don't think the nationality comparison is useful. It's also not relevant to the problem particularly. You probably need a solution where you can automate a headless browser.

Comment: Even if you have 10 different websites to scrape, it still might be easier to look at each of them in turn, and find the best way to get the data you need. Maybe you can simulate one of the AJAX calls directly, rather than scraping it out of the HTML; maybe you can trigger a fallback view which uses less AJAX and is easier to work with; and so on. But if you do need to run JavaScript, then you already know the answer - use a headless browser - and there's not much more to say.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll be able to accomplish it with PHP since it's not a browser and can't run JavaScript. You can use something like [Headless Chromium](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkgr/headless/README.md) and do [`chrome --headless --disable-gpu --dump-dom https://www.chromestatus.com/`](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome#printing_the_dom) which unfortunately can't tell exactly when it's "fully loaded" but you can do it on some type of delay I'm sure.

Comment: I tried to exec that already. It works exactly like the PhantomJS. Unfortunately dealing the a constant time delay is inefficient. Sometimes the delay will not be enough for the page to fully load and for the rest of the times, it just increases the execution time with no need.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like setting JS on page load finish to get all page content to variable, and then sending that variable to php script via Ajax.